# Comparing images one by one from two separate folders and save result in a third folder

Tags: python, opencv

Mentioned code snippet compares first image and then keep running for remaining images in 2nd loop which is wrong.

I want that after comparing first image from both loops it will go back for 2nd image of first loop and compare 2nd image from both the directories and so on and finally difference will be saved in a third folder.

*pseudocode:*

```
imageA = glob.glob("D:\\*.png")
imageB = glob.glob("D:\\*.png")

for imgA in imageA:
  imageA = cv2.imread(imgA)
  grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  print(imgA)
  print(grayA)

  for imgB in imageB:
    imageB = cv2.imread(imgB)
    grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(imgB)
    print(grayB)
```

Comment: You need to understand for nested `for` loops work

Comment: Very wierd request. Looks like you just want to go through set of pairs <A,B> and compare them. But then both set of images are equal, even after processing. Are you sure both that you need "D:\\*.png" for both sides?

Comment: *.png is just a reference (means each folder has hundreds of images)

Comment: https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/detect-and-visualize-differences-between-two-images-with-opencv-python/

Comment: still unclear. not that you want to compare something, but **what** you want to compare. are you really proposing to compare every picture with every other picture? you can do that... but if you don't want to wait forever for it to finish, you need to be smart about it. this is college-level stuff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval